# i am getting Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider when i add the ui.bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the angular bootstrap module. i am getting this error

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

when i add the ui.bootstrap.

I have looked at lot of examples but i am not able to figure it out.

Thanks

**This is my Factory**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('Candidate', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var serviceId = 'conferenceFactory';

app.factory(serviceId, ['$http', conferenceFactory]);

function conferenceFactory($http) {

    var service = {
        getCandidate: getCandidate,
    };

    return service;


    function getCandidate() {
        return $http.get('/api/getcandidate/get');
    }
}
})();
```

**This is my Controller Code**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllerId = 'conferenceController';
 angular.module('Candidate', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', 'conferenceFactory', '$modalInstance',
function ($scope, conferenceFactory, $modalInstance) {

getdata();

function getdata() {

    $scope.candidates = [];
    conferenceFactory.getCandidate().success(function (data) {
        $scope.candidates = data;
    }).error(function (data) {

    });
}

    $scope.showCandidate = function (data) {
        var params = {
            candidate: data,
        };
    };
}
]);

 })();
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the link to the angularbootstrap js file in your index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have added in the links to angular bootstrap files  in your index.html . e.g.

```
 <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i already did. I think there is something wrong in the my angular code that i cannot figure out.